# How can I change the size of drawer/back button icons of appbar without modifying the behavior provided by default in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, icons, appbar

I am trying to change the size of the icons ("Back" provided by Navigator and "Drawer" provided by Scaffold) in appbar in my ThemeData, modifying iconTheme and primaryIconTheme:

```
ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey, size: 32),
    primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey, size: 32)
  ),
```

This lines only changes the color of the icons, but the size does not change.

I do not need to change the behavior that Flutter handles this button, only the size of them.

Answer (score 0):

The AppBar widget uses a [BackButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BackButton-class.html) widget, so that change is not possible unless you modify it from the framework in a different branch, but the best approach is to use the Leading property and the condition ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop to check whether the current route can be popped. For example:

`AppBar(
      leading: ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop == true
          ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                size: 60,
              ),
            )
          : null,
      title: Text(
        "Example",
      ),
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Luis' answer is mostly complete, but note that you will need to define the `onPressed` callback in the IconButton, shown below:

```
AppBar(
      leading: ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop == true
          ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                size: 60,
              ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), 
// used onPressed here
            )
          : null,
      title: Text(
        "Example",
      ),
    )
```